# Set rules for 'Payment Information' on Onepage Checkout

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, rules

I'd like to add in some rules for the 'Payment Information' section of the Magento Onepage Checkout.

Currently my site will show the options:

- Debit/Credit Card
- PayPal
- Invoice Organisation

I'd like to only show the 'Invoice' option if they have selected a particular option within the Billing Payment section.

Which file should I edit to access the options within the Payment Section on the onepage checkout? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres a really handy event for disabling and enabling payment methods on the fly.

Add the following into your config.xml  section

```
<payment_method_is_active>
    <observers>
        <preorder_payment>
            <class>your_module/observers</class>
            <method>invoiceOnly</method>
        </preorder_payment>
    </observers>
</payment_method_is_active>
```

Then create the following function in your observer.php

```
/**
 * Disable all other payments
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 */
public function invoiceOnly(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

    $_result = $observer->getResult();
    $_methodInstance = $observer->getMethodInstance();

    if(BILLING_CONDITION_HERE) {
        if($_methodInstance->getCode() != 'METHOD_CODE') {
            $_result->isAvailable = false;
        } else {
            $_result->isAvailable = true;
        }
    }

}
```

You'll need to modify the **BILLING_CONDITION_HERE** and the **METHOD_CODE** (to the invoice payment method code)

This will automatically disable everything except **METHOD_CODE** if the billing condition is met.

Comment: Dave... awesome :)

Comment: @Zabs no problem :)

Comment: Thank you. It works fine for my custom logic as well. However, I've got a question about controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling event, which is fired after payment_method_is_active. It's problematic because I'm trying to enable/disable some payment methods depending of user address. Do you have an idea which event should I use after address is saved and before payment methods are displayed?

Answer (score 1):

you can disable

> Paypal Payment module

From

> Admin->system->configure->Payment Methods->Paypal

Similarly You can disable credit card from admin:

> Admin->system->configure->Saved CC

and select disable option.

Comment: The OP is looking to disable payment options depending on user input. This would disable the option entirely.